# Extract URL containing /find/ from numerous URL's?

Tags: php, regex

I'm really a major novice at RegEx and could do with some help.

I have a long string containing lots of URL's and other text, and one of the URL's contains has /find/ in it. ie:

```
1. http://www.example.com/not/index.html
2. http://www.example.com/sat/index.html
3. http://www.example.com/find/index.html
4. http://www.example.com/rat/mine.html
5. http://www.example.com/mat/find.html
```

What sort of RegEx would I use to return the URL that is number 3 in that list but not return me number 5 as well? I suppose basically what I'm looking for is a way of returning a whole word that contains a specific set of letters and / in order.

TIA

Comment: How is the data stored? In an array?

Comment: A long string with line breaks? I assume it doesn't have line numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you want `preg_match("%/find/%",$input);` or similar.

EDIT: To get the full line, use:

```
preg_match("%^.*?/find/.*$%m",$input);
```

Comment: If that's all he wants `strpos()` will do the the job. I suspect he wants to extract the whole URL, which get's distinctly more tricky unless the URLs are quite rigidly defined, given the potential entropy in URLs

Comment: Yes I wanted the whole word that the pattern appeared in.

Comment: @EricBanderhide Do the links appear as you showed them, without `http://`? Are they always to the same domain?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to use [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to generate regular expressions.

You can type in a sample list (like the one above) and use a palette to create a RegExp and test it in realtime. The program is available both online and as downloadable Adobe AIR package.

Unfortunately I cannot access their site now, so I'm attaching [the AIR package of the downloadable version](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9287758/Programmi%20consigliati/RegExr.air).

I really recommend you this, since it helped a RegExp newbie like me to design even the most complex patterns.

However, for your question, I think that just

```
\/find\/
```

goes well if you want to obtain a yes/no result (i.e. if it contains or not `/find/`), otherwise to obtain the full line use

```
.*\/find\/.*
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kolink's answer, in case you wanted to regex match the whole URI:

This is **by no means** an exhaustive regex for URIs, but [this is a good starting point](http://rubular.com/r/mRqZuNAG9h). I threw in a few options at key points, like `.com`, `.net`, and `.org`. In reality you'll have a fairly hard time matching URIs with regular expressions due to the lack of conformity, but you can come very close

The regex from the above link:

`/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\.(com|org|net)\/(find)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\.(html|php|aspx)?/is`